# Why are .NET API Browser examples written in C++ instead of C#?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, api, reference

I'm really excited by the way Microsoft documentation about C# organized and expected examples of using this language (as main for platform) in .NET API Reference. But unexpectedly I found examples just on C++ ? For example, [Calendar Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.calendar?view=netframework-4.8). Why is it so and is it possible to find .NET API Reference examples in C# ?

Comment: In Remarks section you have a link to page which describe how to use this class in C#.

Comment: That link shows C# for me...

Comment: Thank you all. I used the link from phone browser – language change didn't seem obvious. Shame on me.

Answer (score 2):

Change the language to C#.  It is in the drop-down in the breadcrumbs bar as shown in the image below: [image]

Answer (score 2):

They're written in C++, C#, F# and VB.NET. Use the drop-down at the top to change the language.

[image: language dropdown]

Answer (score 0):

As for why it's so, the example is C++/CLI, a variant of C++ Microsoft invented which compiles to CLR bytecode and can use managed memory and the .NET API.